# Electromechanical solution for opening the charging port of electric vehicle

Tags: circuit-design, switches, relay, electric-vehicle

Below image shows the charging port of my ev. Currently if I want to charge the vehicle I will manually open the port cover(the white color one in the image).

**My intention is to place a switch in the bike and whenever I need to charge I will press the switch and the white colored lid will open and once the charging is completed I will close it manually**. I need to place a sensor also to check whether it is closed properly. The sensor circuit is connected to VCU.

I have some idea about sensor section. **My question is any circuit idea for opening the lid.**

[image]

Comment: What problem will it solve, when opening the lid using a push button instead of just opening it? Also we don't know how the lid is currently opened. Do you just need to lift it? Do you need to push it down to release a latch? What amount of force is required? This is mostly a mechanical question. You can always move something mechanically, but will your DIY solution work under harsh automotive environment?

Comment: Thank you. Currently it is opened manually, you need to just lift it. Yes I need a push button to release the latch. Force I have not calculated yet. Now started exploring some circuit ideas for POC.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Analogkid You can't explore circuit ideas until you have determined what kind of actuator you will be using. Then you need to explore what circuits you need to drive the actuator.

Comment: Looks like you need a motor driver circuit.